# Manage multiple Dockefile with same libraries

Tags: go, dockerfile

I have the following folder structure:

```
/go/src/[my-private-repo]
  /my-libraries
  go.mod
  go.sum
  main.go
  Dockerfile
```

That's great, it works.

However I want to add another main2.go and another Dockerfile2 to have this strucutre. In my mind:

```
/go/src/[my-private-repo]
  /my-libraries
  go.mod
  go.sum
  /build1
    main.go
    Dockerfile
  /build2
    main.go
    Dockerfile
```

However, docker does not allow this .

My current Dockerfile copies the content of my local file system to build the image. It does not fetch [my-private-repo].

```
FROM golang:1.15 as builder

WORKDIR /go/src/[my-private-repo]
ADD . .
# Build the application
RUN go build -o /build/main .
# ...
```

I do think that I am missing some obvious step.

Any suggestions on how to have different main.go and Dockerfile using the same libraries.
Do I have to

Answer (score 0):

I end up doing the following:

```
/go/src/[my-private-repo]
  /my-libraries
  go.mod
  go.sum
  build1.Dockerfile
  /build1
    main.go
  build2.Dockerfile
  /build2
    main.go
```

Content of build1.Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.15 as builder

WORKDIR /go/src/[my-private-repo]
ADD . .
WORKDIR /go/src/[my-private-repo]/build1
# Build the application
RUN go build -o /build/main .
# ...
```

Build first image
`docker build . -t build1 -f build1.Dockerfile`

Content of build2.Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.15 as builder

WORKDIR /go/src/[my-private-repo]
ADD . .
WORKDIR /go/src/[my-private-repo]/build2
# Build the application
RUN go build -o /build/main .
# ...
```

Build second image
`docker build . -t build2 -f build2.Dockerfile`